# sshd with multiple network interfaces, one interface disconnects after about 1 minute

Tags: raspberry-pi, sshd

I am using sshd to connect to a device that has both a wired NIC and wireless NIC. This has been working reliably for months when I initially set it all up. I recently changed the wired NIC to a different network (using VLANs for separation of traffic) and sshd disconnects from the wired NIC rapidly after connection. I usually can type about 2-3 commands before it disconnects. However, sshd is stable on the wireless NIC.

sshd_config is the default. ListenAddress is commented out.

The IP for the wired NIC has constantly up. Although it is hard to confirm if it isn't dropping and coming back quickly. I have been running a continuous ping on it and have a browser open to a web service running on the machine and both seem to never disconnect or stall. I know that isn't a perfect test. I can't find anything meaningful in the logs.

I'd like sshd to run from any IP or NIC. I'm a bit at a loss. Usually I'm pretty good at sleuthing networking issues like this.

Details requested in the comments:
ipables isn't installed

```
$ ip -br link
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>
eth0             UP             b8:27:eb:83:cf:24 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
wlan0            UP             b8:27:eb:d6:9a:71 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

```
 $ ip -br address
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
eth0             UP             192.168.1.3/24 fe80::ccac:4bb2:79a:b067/64
wlan0            UP             192.168.10.212/24 fe80::597b:8ab0:8308:6a38/64
```

```
 $ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.3 metric 202
default via 192.168.10.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.10.212 metric 303
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.3 metric 202
192.168.10.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.10.212 metric 303
```

```
 $ ip neigh
192.168.10.1 dev wlan0 lladdr 00:08:a2:0b:be:3f STALE
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 lladdr 00:08:a2:0b:be:3f REACHABLE
192.168.10.51 dev wlan0 lladdr b4:ae:2b:cd:95:30 REACHABLE
192.168.10.5 dev wlan0 lladdr 74:ac:b9:b0:22:7d REACHABLE
192.168.10.4 dev wlan0 lladdr fc:ec:da:86:1d:47 REACHABLE
```

```
 $ sudo nft list ruleset
```

Comment: The question as-is doesn't help (me) much. You could add information for your case in the question: The network configuration: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip neigh` . You should run `ip neigh` before and after the problem. You should also keep `ip -ts monitor | tee /tmp/monitor.log` running (it's quite verbose but might help later) . Also firewall information like `iptables-save -c; nft list ruleset` : if there is any reject rule (rather than only drop), it could be involved. `tcpdump -n -e ...` (and proper filter: don't capture a remote tcpdump) on both sides could also help.

Comment: I did run the ip monitor watching the logs and I did notice it seems the wlan0 interface has a lot of activity and eth0 just appears to be dormat minus a handful of entries

Comment: Whatever you add, do it by [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/711846/edit)-ing the question please (I did write "in the question" in my 1st comment). Don't write it in comments. About the monitor, don't write it, it will be best used with grep etc when searching for something. You can add `-4` to every `ip` command, there's no ipv6 involved. Anyway it's debug and what you wrote doesn't help with debug (especially `ip neigh` didn't show anything weird). So I won't be able to help further. You should also use `tcpdump -n -e -p -i all` on each system (but not remotely) to help yourself.

Comment: I updated the question. It is very baffling to me. This is a very basic install and I don't see anything in the network config or sshd config to justify this behavior.

Comment: I just reinstalled the stock RPi OS using the imager on a second RPi3 I had only making settings for WiFi and enabling SSH and this second RPi is doing the very same thing and I didn't do anything to it but stock installation.